# Javascript Variable Google Event Tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm trying to use a javascript variable in a bit of Google Event tracking as the value of the event. Every time I use the variable 'productPriceNCI' as the value parameter it breaks. I've confirmed it's an integer, but still no dice. The BigCommerce variable I'm using as the label is working just fine.

Do GA functions accept JS variables? Am I doing something else wrong? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
var productPrice = "60.00";

var productPriceNC = productPrice.replace(/[$]/,'' );

var productPriceNCI = productPriceNC.replace(/\.\d{2}/,'');



if( $('.ErrorMessage').is(':visible') ) {
    new $.flavr({                
        dialog      : 'form',
        form        : { content: html, method: 'post' },
        closeOverlay: true,
        closeEsc    : true,
        onShow      : function(){ 
                        pageTracker._trackEvent('OutOfStock','Popup Displayed','%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%',productPriceNCI);
                    },
        onSubmit    :  function(){
                        pageTracker._trackEvent('OutOfStock','Email','Submit');            
                    }

    });
    $('.ErrorMessage').hide();
};
```

Comment: According to the trackevent documentation, the 4th element should be a number. Your productPriceNCI is a string. Maybe you need to convert it to a real javascript number. +productPriceNCI or Number(productPriceNCI) or parseInt(productPriceNCI)

Comment: Thanks! Prepending a + before the variable worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a string to Number in Javascript:

```
pageTracker._trackEvent('OutOfStock','Popup Displayed','%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%', +productPriceNCI);
```